# Calculate value gap between reporting importers/exporters [R}

Tags: r, dataframe, difference, array-difference

I need to calculate the "Value Gap" between the reported  volume of various commodities. For example (table below), USA reports that they exported 4 apples to China. China reported they they imported 4 (0 apple gap). USA imports 5 oranges from China, China reports that the only exported 4 (1 orange gap). The real problem has 7 countries, 10 comomdities etc.

```
#example data 
Trade.Data <- data.frame(
     Reporter = c("USA","China","USA", "China"), 
     Partner =  c("China","USA","China", "USA"),
     Flow = c("Export", "Import", "Import", "Export"), 
     Commodity = c("apple", "apple","orange", "orange"),
     Volume = c(4,4,5,4)
 )
 
 Trade.Data
  Reporter Partner   Flow Commodity Volume
1      USA   China Export     apple      4
2    China     USA Import     apple      4
3      USA   China Import    orange      5
4    China     USA Export    orange      4
```

The goal is to calculate the difference and append to a new table:

```
Value.Gap
Reporter    Partner  Commodity    Gap
1    China     USA      apple      0
2      USA   China     orange      1
```

I came up with a VERY clunky and slow method that would benefit from loops.

```
#SO CLUNKY
fvalue <- function(dataframe, ReporterCountry, TradeFlow, PartnerCountry, Commodity){
  x <- dataframe %>% filter(
    Reporter == ReporterCountry,
    Flow == TradeFlow,
    Partner == PartnerCountry,
    Commodity == Commodity)
  print (x$Volume)
  
}

USA_import_China_apple <-fvalue(Trade.Data, "USA", "Import", "China", "apple")
China_export_USA_apple <- fvalue(Trade.Data, "China", "Export", "USA", "apple")
gap_USA_China_apple <- USA_import_China_apple - China_export_USA_apple
gap_USA_China_apple

 USA_import_China_apple <-fvalue(Trade.Data, "USA", "Import", "China", "apple")
[1] 5
> China_export_USA_apple <- fvalue(Trade.Data, "China", "Export", "USA", "apple")
[1] 4
> gap_USA_China_apple <- USA_import_China_apple - China_export_USA_apple
> gap_USA_China_apple
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I add two more rows to make myself clear, please let me know it's wrong.

```
Trade.Data <- data.frame(
  Reporter = c("USA","China","USA", "China", "USA", "UK"), 
  Partner =  c("China","USA","China", "USA", "UK", "USA"),
  Flow = c("Export", "Import", "Import", "Export", "Import", "Export"), 
  Commodity = c("apple", "apple","orange", "orange", "apple", "apple"),
  Volume = c(4,4,5,4, 3, 5)
)

  Reporter Partner   Flow Commodity Volume
1      USA   China Export     apple      4
2    China     USA Import     apple      4
3      USA   China Import    orange      5
4    China     USA Export    orange      4
5      USA      UK Import     apple      3
6       UK     USA Export     apple      5
```

Using `stringr::str_split`, `library(dplyr)`,

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

Trade.Data %>%
  mutate(key = ifelse(
    Flow == "Import",
    paste0(Reporter, "-",Partner),
    paste0(Partner, "-",Reporter)
  )) %>%
  group_by(Commodity, key) %>%
  summarize(Gap = abs(diff(Volume))) %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(Reporter = str_split(key, "-", simplify = T)[1],
         Partner = str_split(key, "-", simplify = T)[2]) %>%
  select(-key)

  Commodity   Gap Reporter Partner
  <chr>     <dbl> <chr>    <chr>  
1 apple         0 China    USA    
2 apple         2 USA      UK     
3 orange        1 USA      China
```

Comment: Thanks Park - It's close. The output results in incorrect info. There are two listings for China & USA apples (0 is the correct answer; 2 is incorrect). And no listing for the UK & USA apple (where two would be the difference).

Comment: Would splitting it into two tables - one where USA isreporting import, the other where the reporting country is the exporter. Then using the commodity as the key between the two tables to calculate the difference between volume?

Comment: @CLancaster I'm sorry, that it gave me correct answer until ` summarize(Gap = abs(diff(Volume)))` but got wrong when `str_split`. I edit this part that gives correct answer.

Comment: @CLancaster I cannot understand other question. Can you give me an example for that?(Would splitting it into two tables..... part)

Comment: the second wasn't a question, it was an idea for a solution of the reporting issue. I removed everything after ```rowise``` is spot on. This definitely will help me apply to the more complicated data set.